# try_files in Nginx config doesn't seem to work with symlinked paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

If I have:

```
try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;

location @app {
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_pass http://app
}
```

When I create a file at foo/bar/baz.txt it works but if 'bar' is a symlink, it stops working. Anyone know how to solve this as I need to use symlinks.

Comment: Does nginx have enough rights to follow that symlink?

Comment: Ah, I was being daft, there was not executable rights for all on one of the parent directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was being daft, there was not executable rights for all on one of the parent directories.